# Syntax error even after replacement of keyword in field name in mysql table schema?

Tags: mysql

Here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice_item
(
    _id                    BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    invoice_id             BIGINT,
    item                   CHAR(11) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
    # One of:
    #   - 'D': Default
    #   - 'M': Meta
    type                   CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
    order                  INT NOT NULL,
    status                 CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
    INDEX (invoice_id, item, status, order)
);
```

And I got this error message

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'order                  INT NOT NULL,

I am using mysql 8 on AWS RDS.

I am not sure if it is because 'order' is a reserved keyword.

I have replaced 'order' with 'rank' (to avoid using a keyword) but mysql still throws a syntax error at the same spot.

What is exactly the syntax error there?

Comment: Have you tried `order` instead? Using these backward apostrophies?

Comment: It's a keyword, but you can by using backticks: `\`order\``

Comment: Question updated. Even if I replaced order with rank there is still a syntax error. But I am not to tell what it is.

Comment: Wrong quotes, those are NOT the same as backticks. The character usually located below the ESC key, on the same key with `~`

Comment: I have replaced the keyword with another word rank, without quote at all, but still get the same error message.

Comment: @Barmar Not a duplicate. See edited version of the question.

Comment: Know that `type` and `status` are keywords too. You can easily google [the reserved keyword list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-T)

Comment: @PaulT. You're right. Type is also a keyword.

Comment: And `RANK` became a reserved word in 8.0.2.

Comment: @Bamar Thanks for the heads up! Appreciate it.